# Should you use both a Wordmark and a Lettermark Logo together at the same time?

Tags: logo, typography, design-principles, lettering

Is it bad design to use BOTH a company wordmark (pictures to the right) and a Lettermark (pictured to the left) at the same time in a header of a website or app? or on a businesss card? or ever?

[image: FB logo]

Comment: I imagine this is only ever an issue if the two can spell a different word somehow. **CO** Ckedit Options. In this example, Ckedit Options, my made up company could letter mark their initials **CO**, but when put too closely together would be...unfortunate.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question:

> Should you use both a Wordmark and a Lettermark Logo together at the
>   same time?

It depends. Not all cases are the same, and in the end it will be a decision that should be validated by testing.

However, when you ask:

> Is it bad design to use BOTH a company wordmark (pictures to the
>   right) and a Lettermark (pictured to the left) at the same time in a
>   header of a website or app? or on a businesss card? or ever?

Then the answer is a loud **NO!**.

Think about this: **your example is one of the most famous brands ever.** In that scenario, you can add a lettermark (I'd dispute that the F is a lettermark, but anyways), a wordmark, a combination logo or whatever you want. Just because you can.

**But in the 99.99% of cases in which you're NOT one of the most famous brands ever...** how do you expect users to make the connection between the different parts of your branding if you don't show it? So the obvious answer is: **not only is not bad design, but you HAVE to put them together.** *Otherwise you'd be relying on magic!*